# iOS - How to convert CGPoint to view coordinates?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my iOS app, have used `CIDetector` for detecting the rectangle. From that I am getting the rectangles as four `CGPoint` values.

But i need to convert into the view coordinates, so that i can assess the  angle of the rectangle.

```
- (CIRectangleFeature *)_biggestRectangleInRectangles:(NSArray *)rectangles
{
if (![rectangles count]) return nil;

float halfPerimiterValue = 0;

CIRectangleFeature *biggestRectangle = [rectangles firstObject];

for (CIRectangleFeature *rect in rectangles)
{
    CGPoint p1 = rect.topLeft;
    CGPoint p2 = rect.topRight;
    CGFloat width = hypotf(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);

    CGPoint p3 = rect.topLeft;
    CGPoint p4 = rect.bottomLeft;
    CGFloat height = hypotf(p3.x - p4.x, p3.y - p4.y);

    CGFloat currentHalfPerimiterValue = height + width;

    if (halfPerimiterValue < currentHalfPerimiterValue)
    {
        halfPerimiterValue = currentHalfPerimiterValue;
        biggestRectangle = rect;
    }
}

return biggestRectangle;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is uncleared, its better if you specify your question more properly.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my own question.

Using below method i can find the distance between two CGPoints, Based on the distances i could find the angle of the images.

```
- (CGFloat)calcDistanceFromCGPoints:(CGPoint )pt1 point2:(CGPoint )pt2{
CGPoint p2 = pt2;
CGPoint p1 = pt1;
//Assign the coord of p2 and p1...
//End Assign...
CGFloat xDist = (p2.x - p1.x); //[2]
CGFloat yDist = (p2.y - p1.y); //[3]
CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)); //[4]
return distance;
}

-(NSString *)getDirection{

CGFloat width1 = [self calcDistanceFromCGPoints:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.bottomRight point2:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.bottomLeft];
CGFloat width2 = [self calcDistanceFromCGPoints:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.topRight point2:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.topLeft];
CGFloat height1 = [self calcDistanceFromCGPoints:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.bottomLeft point2:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.topLeft];
CGFloat height2 = [self calcDistanceFromCGPoints:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.bottomRight point2:_borderDetectLastRectangleFeature.topRight];

CGFloat absWidth = fabs(width2 - width1);
CGFloat absHeight = fabs(height2 - height1);

NSString *direction = @"";
if(absWidth > absHeight){
    CGFloat heightDiff = height1-height2;
    if((width1-width2) > 0){                // BOTTOM
        if(heightDiff > 0){
            if(heightDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"BottomLeft";
            else
                direction = @"Bottom";
        }
        else{
            if(heightDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"BottomRight";
            else
                direction = @"Bottom";
        }
    }
    else{                                   // TOP
        if(heightDiff > 0){
            if(heightDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"TopLeft";
            else
                direction = @"Top";
        }
        else{
            if(heightDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"TopRight";
            else
                direction = @"Top";
        }
    }
}
else{
    CGFloat widthDiff = width1-width2;      // LEFT
    if((height1-height2) > 0){
        if(widthDiff > 0){
            if(widthDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"TopLeft";
            else
                direction = @"Left";
        }
        else{
            if(widthDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"BottomLeft";
            else
                direction = @"Left";
        }
    }
    else{                                   // RIGHT
        if(widthDiff > 0){
            if(widthDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"TopRight";
            else
                direction = @"Right";
        }
        else{
            if(widthDiff > DIRECTION_DIFF)
                direction = @"TopLeft";
            else
                direction = @"Right";
        }
    }
}
return direction;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want convert point to map coordinate, you can try with:

```
open func convert(_ point: CGPoint, toCoordinateFrom view: UIView?) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

it's a function of `MKMapView`